# Can't seem to transform KStream<A,B> to KTable<X,Y>

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

This is my first attempt at trying to use a `KTable`.  I have a Kafka Stream that contains Avro serialized objects of type `A,B`.  And this works fine.  I can write a Consumer that consumes just fine or a simple `KStream` that simply counts records.

The `B` object has a field containing a country code.  I'd like to supply that code to a KTable so it can count the number of records that contain a particular country code.  To do so I'm trying to convert the stream into a stream of `X,Y` (or really: country-code, count).  Eventually I look at the contents of the table and extract an array of KV pairs.

The code I have (included) always errors out with the following (**see** the line with 'Caused by'):

```
2018-07-26 13:42:48.688 [com.findology.tools.controller.TestEventGeneratorController-16d7cd06-4742-402e-a679-898b9ef78c41-StreamThread-1; AssignedStreamsTasks] ERROR -- stream-thread [com.findology.tools.controller.TestEventGeneratorController-16d7c\
d06-4742-402e-a679-898b9ef78c41-StreamThread-1] Failed to process stream task 0_0 due to the following error:
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=com.findology.model.traffic.CpaTrackingCallback, partition=0, offset=962649
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:240)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:411)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:922)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:749)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:719)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.Integer / value type: java.lang.Integer). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:92)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:211)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamTransform$KStreamTransformProcessor.process(KStreamTransform.java:59)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:211)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:224)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [B
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:21)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:146)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:87)
        ... 19 more
```

And here is the code I'm using.  I've omitted certain classes for brevity. **Note** that I'm *not* using the Confluent KafkaAvro classes.

```
    private synchronized void createStreamProcessor2() {
    if (streams == null) {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, getClass().getName());
            props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);

            StreamsConfig config = new StreamsConfig(props);
            StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

            Map<String, Object> serdeProps = new HashMap<>();
            serdeProps.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryURL);
            AvroSerde<CpaTrackingCallback> cpaTrackingCallbackAvroSerde = new AvroSerde<>(schemaRegistryURL);
            cpaTrackingCallbackAvroSerde.configure(serdeProps, false);

            // This is the key to telling kafka the specific Serde instance to use
            // to deserialize the Avro encoded value
            KStream<Long, CpaTrackingCallback> stream = builder.stream(CpaTrackingCallback.class.getName(),
                            Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), cpaTrackingCallbackAvroSerde));

            // provide a way to convert CpsTrackicking... info into just country codes
            // (Long, CpaTrackingCallback) -> (countryCode:Integer, placeHolder:Long)
            TransformerSupplier<Long, CpaTrackingCallback, KeyValue<Integer, Long>> transformer = new TransformerSupplier<Long, CpaTrackingCallback, KeyValue<Integer, Long>>() {
                @Override
                public Transformer<Long, CpaTrackingCallback, KeyValue<Integer, Long>> get() {
                    return new Transformer<Long, CpaTrackingCallback, KeyValue<Integer, Long>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                            // Not doing Punctuate so no need to store context
                        }

                        @Override
                        public KeyValue<Integer, Long> transform(Long key, CpaTrackingCallback value) {
                            return new KeyValue(value.getCountryCode(), 1);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public KeyValue<Integer, Long> punctuate(long timestamp) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void close() {
                        }
                    };
                }
            };

            KTable<Integer, Long> countryCounts = stream.transform(transformer).groupByKey() //
                            .count(Materialized.as("country-counts"));

            streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
            streams.cleanUp();
            streams.start();

            try {
                countryCountsView = waitUntilStoreIsQueryable("country-counts", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore(),
                                streams);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.warn("Interrupted while waiting for query store to become available", e);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The bare `groupByKey()` method on `KStream` uses the default serializer/deserializer (which you haven't set). Use the method `groupByKey(Serialized<K,V> serialized)`, as in:

```
.groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Long()))
```

Also note, what you do in your custom TransformerSupplier, you can do simply with a `KStream.map` call.

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed the immediate issue.  Also, I'll retry using a map instead.